# Parsing Contents of Dropbox File in JavaScript Web App

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

Is it possible using the [Dropbox JS SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/) to create a JavaScript web application that is able to parse the files in a user's Dropbox? In my use case, the user has some JSON files that I would like to parse and preview in the browser. Will the filesDownload(arg) method allow for this type of application, or is it only able to download the file to the user's machine?

Answer (score 0):

The download methods, such as [`filesDownload`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload__anchor) and [`sharingGetSharedLinkFile`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingGetSharedLinkFile__anchor) return the file content directly as a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FBlob), as seen in the [download example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/download/index.html#L51).

As long as you can use a `Blob` to do what you want, this should be possible.